# using CMD data loader to find accounts whos ID is IN List/Array

Tags: soql, data-loader

I have a list of accounts that need to be updated but this list is not available in SF, this is only available in a remote Desktop environment. The accounts in this list do not have a SF ID; they do however have a unique ID that also links to an account. What I would like to do is run through my list of data using CMD and then add this external ID to some sort of list or array and then do an export like thus:

```
SELECT ID, Name, etc FROM Account WHERE my_unique_id IN : Local_Id_list;
```

Is this possible or will I have to perform a local SQL querie or something like that?